# Upgrade already installed ffmpeg software on ubuntu server

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg version 2.2.5 installed on my server which is running on ubuntu. I want to update it to latest version and codecs/libraries.

I have tried the following commands but they are not working.

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
- sudo apt-get update ffmpeg 2.8

( I tried doing the same on my local machine, before I do this on the server, which have ffmpeg 2.4.3 installed and after updating around 238 MB and tons of library. When I run ffmpeg -version or ffmpeg -buildconf it show me the same library and ffmpeg version as before. ) Am I missing something? Do I have to compile it or re-configure it?

Following is current console output for ffmpeg 2.2.5 on my server

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  1 2014 09:24:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100

  configuration:
    --enable-gpl
    --enable-version3
    --enable-nonfree
    --enable-postproc
    --enable-libtheora
    --enable-libx264
    --enable-libvpx
    --enable-libmp3lame
```

I want to upgrade to ffmpeg 2.8 version or atleast 2.4

Please guide me.

**Edit:**

Giving me this menu while running  your mentioned command [installation option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyalu.png). Are we pointing to only ffmpeg package?

Comment: Yes, basically you have to compile the new version yourself or find a third party reposiroty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Ubuntu version is `14.04 LTS`, then you can add this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) from [Doug Mcmahon](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man) to upgrade your version of `ffmpeg`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:mc3man/trusty-media; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade ffmpeg
```

Here's a screenshot to verify:

[image: 1]

Comment: If the answer solved your question then, please [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/727002/119531) by clicking on [the upvote arrow and then the tick below it](http://i.imgur.com/YN8AQkd.png?1).

Comment: I think your command is not pointing to right package.

Comment: @HemantKumar - What is the package that you want? You want `ffmpeg` right?

Comment: @HemantKumar - Even [ffmpeg.org](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux) points to this ppa.

Comment: please see my edit above , i have added the image i get from server asking me about grub something. I don't want to mess up the server. A website is already running there which is currently using ffmpeg old version. I want to install or update a upgraded version there. So I don't want to take any chances.

Comment: @HemantKumar - That's because you have other upgrades waiting for your approval, but if you don't want to do that then copy-paste the command now. I have edited it for you.

Comment: Thanks for updating the command. I am again stuck at certain locks. The following packages will be upgraded:
  ffmpeg
1 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: Is any other application using apt-get?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: A quick restart or logout will solve it

Comment: Its a live server, and i am accessing it using remote terminal . Can we stop apt-get using any command then use our command?

Comment: Do this: `sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.bak` and then try again.

Comment: Ok the uninstalling is working. At the end i get this. Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 apparmor
 byobu
 grub-pc
 landscape-common
 landscape-client
 policykit-1
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
 x11-common
 cloud-init
 grub-legacy-ec2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
.. Also i tried ffmpeg -version and it didn't work. Saying "-bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory"  What does this mean?

Comment: guess it messed something. How can i make ffmpeg install now?

Comment: In the previous command all you did was make a backup of your lock file. You can restore it by typing: `sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.bak /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Comment: so the ffmpeg is gone i guess. when i type whereis ffmpeg. I get this ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/X11/ffmpeg /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz  Does this mean I can freshly install this package?

Comment: You already have `ffmpeg`. This output verifies that `ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg `.

Comment: But ffmpeg not running now.

Comment: How are realizing that it not working?

Comment: I just checked the process depending on ffmpeg is working on server but when i try to check its version on terminal it give me -bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory
this error. And the commands those were earlier working for me on terminal are not showing the same error. I am failing to understand what just happened.

Comment: Do this: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg --version`

Comment: Ok this is working now. So I won't be able to run command directly on the server, for testing purpose? I used to check the command if running, directly on server earlier.

Comment: Which version does it show?

Comment: Would you like to move the conversion to chat? The comment section is getting too long.

Comment: Not sure which version is it. ffmpeg version N-77455-g4707497 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)

Comment: Ok. I am not sure how to chat here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35017/discussion-between-raphael-and-hemant-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Remove curent ffmpeg

```
apt-get remove ffmpeg
```

Add the repository for ffmpeg4

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
```

install ffmpeg

```
apt install -y ffmpeg
```

print out the version.

```
ffmpeg -version
```

Remove the apt repository

```
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
```